# Ошибки связана с weight и resnet50 в tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Ошибки о проблеме говорят, что проблема связана с weight и resnet50:

```
data_generator_with_aug = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input, 
                                             horizontal_flip=True,
                                             width_shift_range=0.2,
                                             height_shift_range=0.2)
train_path='C:/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/training2/training'
train_generator = data_generator_with_aug.flow_from_directory(train_path, 
                                                     target_size=(image_size, image_size), 
                                                     batch_size=24,
                                                     class_mode='categorical')

data_generator_with_no_aug = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

validation_path='C:/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/training2/validation'
validation_generator = data_generator_with_no_aug.flow_from_directory(validation_path,
                                                          target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                                                          batch_size=24,
                                                          class_mode='categorical')




resnet_weights_path = 'C:/Tensorflow/workspace/training_demo/training2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
model = Sequential()
model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))

num_classes = 10
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Say not to train first layer (ResNet) model. It is already trained
model.layers[0].trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
steps_per_epoch=3, 
epochs=20, 
validation_data=validation_generator, 
validation_steps=1)
```

Мой самый первый проект на Tensorflow, помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос. Использую предварительно обученную модель и свои картинки, а также свой json файл с классами для объектов.

ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Tensorflow\workspace\training_demo\training2\1.py", line 37, in 
> model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling='avg', weights=resnet_weights_path))
> File "C:\Users\kamil.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\resnet.py", line 457, in ResNet50
> return ResNet(stack_fn, False, True, 'resnet50', include_top, weights,
> File "C:\Users\kamil.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\resnet.py", line 207, in ResNet
> model.load_weights(weights)
> File "C:\Users\kamil.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2326, in load_weights
> hdf5_format.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
> File "C:\Users\kamil.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 713, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
> backend.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
> File "C:\Users\kamil.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
> return target(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\kamil.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3804, in batch_set_value
> x.assign(np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype_numpy(x)))
> File "C:\Users\kamil.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py", line 898, in assign
> raise ValueError(
> ValueError: Cannot assign to variable conv3_block1_0_conv/kernel:0 due to variable shape (1, 1, 256, 512) and value shape (512, 128, 1, 1) are incompatible
> PS C:\Users\kamil>